# How to make audio plays automatically on page load or on page change in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make the audio play on page loads or on every new page change using html5 audio element and java script. But it does not play on load, sometimes it works only during ctr + f5 but that is very rarely. I have an application that has multiple html pages and on each page change the different audio plays automatically.

I have tried using localhost live reload i.e Live-server and it works perfectly fine however on opening the application directly from the desktop it fails to work. My application will not run on any server it is a bundle for mobile phone.

```
<audio src="Audio.mp3" id="my_audio" autoplay></audio>

<script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload=function(){
            document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function playaudio(){
                document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
            }
```

```html
<body onload="playaudio()"> 
     <audio src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" id="my_audio" autoplay></audio>
</body>`
```

Comment: I dnt think it will work have tried this before, let me check once again though